# Detect Wallpaper Change

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mavericks

First: I am not a c coder myself, but I have an idea and made some research.
Before going through errands trying to find a coder for this, I would like to ask people with experience on the subject if it's even possible.

Detect if the desktop wallpaper has been changed. (note: I am not asking to get the actual file, only for a way to check change has occurred)

- use key observer or poll desktopImageURLForScreen (will this even give the current path in sandboxed mode?)
- I also found this, but it does not seem to work
  [Notification when desktop wallpaper changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673045/notification-when-desktop-wallpaper-changes)

Does anybody else now of ways to accomplish this ? Preferably in a sandboxed way.