# Perform actions when background image changed on Mac

Tags: macos, applescript, background-image, desktop-background

Is there any way to listen to, and trigger actions when user `right click` and click `change desktop background` OR when the `background image` is actually changed on OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current desktop image in the shell like this:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "finder" to get posix path of (get desktop picture as alias)'
```

I presume, if you really wanted to, you could create a `launchd` script with `launchctl` and a corresponding plist to check every minute or so to see if it has changed and then do something...

Comment: Thanks, going to see if others have a better idea ;)

Comment: Cool. I shall do likewise - maybe we can all learn something here :-)

Comment: I added answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77966277/4720315